# Binary '+=' : no global operator found which takes type 'Add' C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I'm really stumbling with Operator Overloading. I have here a simple operation overload for addition (+), yet it gives a no global operator found in my class.

Can someone please explain why is this happening and how should I fix it?

***Error Message***:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: exercise 2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>Add.cpp 1>c:\documents and settings\...\exercise 2\add.cpp(15) :
    error C2677: binary '+=' : no global operator found which takes type 'Add' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Documents and Settings\...\Debug\BuildLog.htm" 
1>exercise 2 - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

***Add.h***:

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD

class Add{
public:
    Add(int = 0);   //default constructor
    Add(Add &);     //copy constructor
    ~Add();         //destructor

    Add operator+(Add &);
private:
    int num;
};

#endif
```

***Add.cpp***:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Add.h"

Add::Add(int x){
    num = x;
}

Add Add::operator +(Add &y){
    Add x = *this;
    x.num += y;
    return x;
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: `x.num += y`? Is that supposed to be `x.num += y.num`?

Comment: @chrisjohn016 - what exactly is the rrror message? Please copy ans paste it from the compiler. Also, shouldn't you have a non-member `operator+` that calls a public member function in the class? (I think Ben nailed the answer; and Tartan spotted another error in your code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+=` operator is not overloaded automatically when you overload the `+` operator for your class, like in C# for example. You have to define it yourself. That is also true for `-=`, etc.

You need to define the `+=` operator as a member function, and return a reference to the instance that was operated on:

```
Add& Add::operator += (const Add& rhs) {
    num += rhs.num;
    return *this;
}
```

Your `+` operator should be non-member, and return a new instance that represents the result of the operation:

```
Add operator + (const Add& lhs, const Add& rhs) {
    return Add(lhs.num + rhs.num);
}
```

Also, in `Add.h`:

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD         // should be ADD_H

// in Add:
    Add(Add &);     // should use 'const Add&'
```

Furthermore, you don't need to define your own `copy constructor` and `destructor` if they don't do anything special. Like in the case of `class Add`, you can just leave them out and let the compiler generate them for you.

Comment: Thanks! just a quick question, why does operator + had two arguments where in my prototypes is just one argument, and when I add another argument in my prototype, i got an error?

Comment: Member `operator+` only takes 1 argument because its second argument is the `this` pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to add an `Add` to an `int`. Change `x.num += y` to `x.num += y.num`.

Additionally, `operator+` is generally best implemented as a free-standing function for symmetry.

Comment: what do you mean free-standing function for symmetry?

Comment: Implementing operators as non-member functions allows implicit conversions on the left-hand-side of expressions; as a member-function, only rhs conversions are allowed.

Comment: Add.h becomes like this:

Comment: #ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H

class Add{
 Add operator+(Add &); //made it non-member
public:
 Add(int = 0); //default constructor
 Add(Add &);  //copy constructor
 ~Add();   //destructor
 int num;
private:
 
};

#endif

Comment: Add operator +(Add &y){
 Add x = *this;
 x.num += y.num;
 return x;
}

Comment: No, that's still a member function.

Comment: it became Global function right? i got this error: error C2673: 'operator +' : global functions do not have 'this' pointers

Comment: You need to make a function with the signature `Add operator+ (const Add&, const Add&)` and not use `this`. Have a look at @Beta's answer.